# Which system error should my libfuse filesystem return when attempting to read from a file that's not open?

Tags: linux, fuse

I'm implementing a libfuse filesystem. When a file is opened, I read the file attributes and store them in a hash table keyed with the file handle I generate. This serves two purposes: to maintain a collection of open file handles and to cache the information I retrieve during opening.

Of course, nothing is stopping user code from trying to pass an invalid file handle, i.e. read from a file that's not open.

There are a number of [error codes](https://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) that I can return from the `read` function, but it's not clear to me which is the one that is expected in such situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [in the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html), the correct value to return would be `EBADF`:

> [EBADF] The fildes argument is not a valid file descriptor open for
>   reading.

That said, if user code passes an invalid file handle, the Linux kernel will return `EBADF` to the user before you, or fuse, get any say on the matter.

Comment: Is that true? In the case of fuse, I was under the impression that it doesn't reach the kernel. The file handles I maintain are values that the kernel doesn't have any knowledge about.

Comment: The file handles you maintain are quite separate from the file handles that user code can use. User code only gets numbers. Kernel uses `struct file` (and returns `EBADF` if the number doesn't map to `struct file`). Fuse kernel module converts `struct file` to a serialized request that libfuse reads and turns into `fuse_req_t`, which is what your code sees.